# Laravel Exception Controller not found

Tags: php, laravel

What is the usual reason for this Laravel error when the controller itself exists?

**Error**

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\TestController does not exist

Code Excerpt:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('index', 'TestController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
public function index()
     //stuff
}
```

Comment: The usual reason? Because the class doesn't exist. How are you referencing it in your `routes.php` file? Is it spelled/capitalized correctly?

Comment: And is your `TestController` namespaced correctly?

Comment: @camel it's spelled and namespaced correctly

Comment: Then it _should be_ working. I'd suggest providing us the actual controller code, instead of an excerpt; it'll help us see more of the issue. Because from what you're stating, it should work...

Comment: It's was running on the wrong server, now it's working, Thanks.